# xgettext not picking up string from a specific directory only

Tags: python-3.x, sh, xgettext

I have python 3.5 application using tornado. I had separated my application in 4 directories:

app/
--- admin
--- server
--- admin_static
--- server_static

and collecting string for the .po file is strange because never is going inside the app/admin folder to collect the strings.

**When i run for app/server and app/server_static is collecting from both directories, but when i run for app/admin and app/admin_static is just collecting from app/admin_static and ignoring this directory app/admin**

```
find ../../admin ../../admin_static -iregex '.*\.\(py\|html\|js\)$' | xargs xgettext --language=Python --from-code utf-8 --keyword=_:1,2 -o ./locale.pot
```

**when i run just this find ../../admin is working but with both directories is not working**

Thanks in  advance for nay recommendation or any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting on Ubuntu, the answer was found.

Sometimes the directory was ignored because was running the command bash in Windows, seems on windows is not so stable, after running same command on Ubuntu everything works fine.